# Getting area covered by intersection or junction?

Tags: openstreetmap, intersection, area, osmosis

I need a way to get following information for each intersection or junction in Berlin:

- latitude and longitude
- area covered

I could get all Junctions from openstreetmap as nodes, which would give me the lat/lon, but not the area covered.

Any solutions?

Comment: Can you get any information about road width? If so, area could be estimated (at least for perpendicular crossings) by multiplying the road widths. Ex. if a 20m wide road crosses a 10m wide road there will be an area of 200m^2 of overlap (i.e. the intersection).

Comment: @ycartwhelen good idea but I think the datasets I found so far don't containt the width (but some do the length).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OSM usually doesn't contain the exact outline of a junction or intersection (except in very few cases where [`area:highway`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:area:highway) has been mapped) and most roads don't have a [`width`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:width) set.

However you can try to estimate it by looking at the [`highway`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway) class (i.e. primary, secondary, tertiary...) and the number of [`lanes`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:lanes).

Comment: Thanks, that sounds reasonable. Is there an easy way to get all streets ("highways") of an intersection? How do you get the intersections anyway?

Comment: An intersection is defined by at least two [ways](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way) sharing the same [node](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node) (and the node *not* being the start or end of the way). See [elements](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) and [OSM XML](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) in case you are still trying to find out how OSM internals work.

So [download](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data) the ways (and their nodes) at the intersections you are interested in, or of the whole city. Overpass API will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but do you know a way how to extract the relevant nodes, off the top of your head? Like osmosis maybe?

Comment: I've never done this myself but osmosis is definitely able to extract the nodes for all ways you are interested in. Alternatively take a look at [osmium-tool](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/) which is more modern and faster than osmosis.